# Raphael Paper.setSize issue

Tags: javascript, raphael

Hello and thank you in advance for your assistance. I've been beating my head against the keyboard all day on this one and need some help. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and Raphael so hopefully it isn't something obvious - but I have spent a good deal of time Googling, checking the docs, and searching this site for answers to no avail.

I'm working on a project that requires elements be draggable accross the canvas in much the same way as in the example posted to the Raphael homepage: http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html
I've got everything working perfectly with one exception - when the user re-sizes the browser window the canvas size is not updating accordingly. Rather, despite the fact that the canvas correctly reports the new dimensions (via output to the console), I cannot drag any of the elements past the canvas' original x/y boundary.

Here are the relevant snippets of code:

CSS:

```
#canvas_container {  
background-color: #696969;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    shadow: 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
    margin-right: 310px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    min-width: 640px;
    min-height: 640px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

JavaScript/Raphael:

```
        //initialize canvas 
    fiddle.paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById("canvas_container"), $('#canvas_container').width(), $('#canvas_container').height()); 

    //resize handler
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
        this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {$(this).trigger('resizeEnd');}, 300);            
    });

    $(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
    //resize canvas
    fiddle.paper.setSize($('#canvas_container').width(), $('#canvas_container').height());

    });
```

What the heck am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off - thanks to those who responded! Interacting with you guys helped me figure out what was going on.

It turns out the issue isn't the Raphael Canvas at all, but the plugin I'm using to handle drag/drop (Raphael.FreeTransform). Unlike the native Raphael drag/drop handler, FreeTransform sets boundaries to prevent the user from dragging an object off the canvas. The default boundaries are set to the boundaries of the canvas. When you resize the canvas via paper.setSize(), the plugin won't update the boundaries unless you explicitly tell it you via [the boundary option](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform/blob/master/README.md#boundary--x-int-y-int-width-int-height-int---false). This is what the working resize code looks like:

```
        //resize handler
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
        this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {$(this).trigger('resizeEnd');}, 300);


    });

    $(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
    //resize canvas
        fiddle.paper.setSize($('#canvas_container').width(), $('#canvas_container').height());

        for (var i = 0; i < fiddle.ftArray.length; i ++) {
            fiddle.ftArray[i].setOpts({boundary: {x: 0, y: 0, width: $('#canvas_container').width(), height: $('#canvas_container').height() }});

        }


    });
```

(ftArray is an array of FreeTransform objects created on window load)

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that your `$(#canvas_container)` dimensions are correctly logged, the `setSize` call should work.

You can compare with my working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexis_tondelier/HGZ4S/). You will especially take care about any `setViewBox` call you could have made, that would imply some contraints to the viewport boundaries. In case you have those contraints, you will have to update your viewbox yourself cause the update on the viewbox made by Raphael on `setSize` being called is not always fully consistent.

Comment: I'm not messing about with setViewBox. I also probably should have mentioned that I'm using the raphael.free_transform plugin to handle the drag/drop stuff. I can see from your jsfiddle that the boundaries of what's visible to the user seem to be updating with when the user re-sizes the window. However, I'm wondering if the canvas is actually cut off at that point, or if your animated box is spinning about unseen by the user. The delay in animation makes me think this might be so. I'm working on a 'forked' fiddle to demonstrate - will post in a tic.

Comment: I made a fiddle but it doesn't exhibit the same behavior as my project and I'm starting to suspect the culprit is the raphael.free_transform plugin - which I'm using to handle the dragging. In the fiddle, I'm using Raphael's built in drag handler which allows the user to drag elements off the canvas - making them irretrievable. In my project using the plugin, element position is restricted by the canvas and the user can't drag them out of bounds. It's that boundary that isn't being updated by paper.setSize. Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gHJJ6/24/

Comment: Either you find a way to tell the plugin the new walls or you use native drag and compute walls yourself. It can be very costless cause it can be computed once on dragstart. For translation you just compute the dx and dy boundaries, thus computing 4 floats.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using the native drag function if possible because I'm pretty sure it doesn't handle path objects in the same way it handles things like circles and rectangles. The nice thing about the plugin is that lets me avoid dealing with translating x/y values to transform values and vice versa. 

I'm going to catch some shuteye (it's 4am here) and investigate the plugin code tomorrow. I've already checked their website and don't see a bug posted, so if I find that it's the culprit I'll post one and make sure to post the resolution here as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need support for IE7-8 then auto-resizing can be very simple:

```
fiddle.paper = new Raphael("canvas_container", '100%','100%');
```

Comment: I already tried this solution, but it allows the user to drag elements way off the canvas and drop them into areas from which they can not be retrieved (something that's also possible in the graffle example on the raphaeljs website)